# Android button method bug

Tags: android, button

I'm creating a new Android application in which i'm using two dialog boxes that contain two buttons each.
At first, I had no problems with the buttons included in the first box, but with the second, I had an annoying one:
Every time I implement the method `public void onClick(View v)` the program compiles just fine, but when I launch the application a message appear:
"Unfortunately app_name has stopped".

I thought that there was a problem with the implementation inside that method, but after testing it, I've discovered that if I change the id of the button into another one that isn't related to the layout of the second dialog box, the program works just fine.

Comment: Can you show the exception in the logcat? Also, show the code for the button click handling.

Comment: the button click handling:

nop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                d_box.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "person has not been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

the exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Add this to the original question

Answer (score 0):

You can't set component of view that isn't setContentView of the current activity

```
Button nop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel5);
```

*nop* = null, in your case.

For your requirements, you need to create a custom dialog, i think.
See the aswer of this post :

[How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

Hope it will help you.

**Update from 07/26/2015**

I think you should use this :
Button btn = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.xxxxx);

d correspond to the dialog boxes.

Comment: sure i did: 
 Button nop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel5);
If i replace the id "cancel5" by another button id that isn't related to the dialog box layout, everything works just fine.

Comment: Have you used AlertDialog or a things like this ? because if so i'm not sur you can use button.

Comment: No i didn't use an AlertDialog, and the problem is that i did almost the same things with the first dialog box(the two buttons worked just fine with it), but with the second one it didn't.

Comment: Same problem occured.

Comment: ok. Can you show the piece of code where the error is present ?

Comment: <code>
 final Dialog d_box=new Dialog(this);
 d_box.setContentView(R.layout.effacer);
 d_box.setTitle("delete a person");
 Button nop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel5);
        nop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "person has not been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 });
</code>